# Tornado - Send message to client on demand

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using Tornado to serve a html file and, at the same time, I want my Python program to dynamically change a value in the same page through websockets. The purpose is that the value can be seen changing, without the need to refresh on the client side.

In this case, I want to send a message with a variable that changes from "1234" to "4321" every 4 seconds. 
I have a thread doing the value toggling and I want that same thread to send that value to the websocket, so I can handle it with a script using the onmessage function in the client side.

The following code will give me the following error: 'Application' object has no attribute 'write_message'

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import threading
import time

flag = True

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("mypage.html")

class wshandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        self.write_message('connected')
            print "WebSocket opened"
    def on_message(self, message):
            self.write_message("You have sent: " + message)
    def on_close(self):
            print "WebSocket closed"
    def write_message(self, message):
        print ("writing message", message)
        self.write_message(message)

application = tornado.web.Application(
    handlers=[
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/ws", wshandler),
        ])

def toggle():
    global flag
    while True:
        if flag==True:
            print 'now on 1234'
            flag = False
            application.write_message('1234')
            time.sleep(4)

        elif flag==False:
            flag = True
            application.write_message('4321')
            print 'Now on 4321'
            time.sleep(4)

def main():
    global response
    valueThread=threading.Thread(target=toggle, name="Toggle Value Thread")
    valueThread.setDaemon(True)
    valueThread.start() 
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My problem is that every single tutorial/guide I've seen about Tornado only uses the function write_message within the open and onmessage function within the websocket class.. so I don't really get why this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should *only use the function write_message within the open and onmessage function within the websocket class*. You are using `application`, which is a `tornado.web.Application`. It certainly won't have the method of `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler`. They are not the same class. Hence the error.

I would do something like:

```
class wshandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def toggle(self):
        flag = True
        while True:
            if flag==True:
                print 'now on 1234'
                flag = False
                self.write_message('1234')
                time.sleep(4)

            elif flag==False:
                flag = True
                self.write_message('4321')
                print 'Now on 4321'
                time.sleep(4)

    def on_message(self, message):
        if message == 'toggle':
            self.toggle()
```

Comment: Thank you. But now how do I use that function wshandler.toggle inside a thread for a constant loop? Making a thread with target=wshandler.toggle will cause an error.. And why do I still need the "onmessage" function in it?

Comment: I'm just asuming that you will start toggle when receiving some kind of message like 'toggle'. Does this wshandler only to do this one job or what?

Comment: Toggle will start as a thread, and that thread will start in the main function.

I don't want toggle to start after the server receives a message. I want toggle to send an unsolicited message. It's just the server sending, and not waiting for a requesting.

Comment: @DanielPina  Websoket is based on TCP which needs handshake before trasnferring data. You need UDP to "just send" the data.

Comment: @DanielPina I think toggling on the server side is not really necessary, or a good practice. This kind of thing should be handled on the client side using Javascript. Server side should focus only on content generating.

Comment: Changing a value (toggle) is simply a way to get the method right to do something else more complex. In this case, I'll want to send a changing variable that will update a chart very fast in the front end, at about 4ms (or at least the fastest I can get it to update)

Having the front-end sending a request for every update on that variable will add a latency I want to avoid, hence my choice for websockets.